# How does Chrome count write operations for bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension that needs to create many bookmarks and folders.

My problem is, that I don't understand, how Chrome counts the write requests that are limited by the value of `chrome.bookmarks.MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE`.

Last week I created about 1000 bookmarks in a loop to test that limit - the bookmarks were all created and after it I could delete them with the API, too.
Today I also tested an extension, that synced all my ~500 bookmarks from Pinboard - without any problem.

But now (after some write operations while developing) I receive an error on every single write operation that tells me, that the limit has exceeded. Even after ~30min of waiting and not touching the API.

So my question is: how does Google count that operations / when does it block my operations?
And why didn't it block i.e. the Pinboard-Extension?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kill and restart your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably banned. Understand that chrome.bookmarks and chrome.storage involve usage of server-side resources via syncing. When you create a large number of requests, it doesn't affect just your own machine; it affects the sync servers, too.

Because the limit was put in place to protect against abuse/bugs and help provide a reliable service for all users, it's unlikely anyone will give you a better answer than the official documentation. Abusers would use that information to their advantage. I know you're not trying to abuse the sync service, but others might, which is why the real limits aren't published anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome maintains an in-memory blacklist of extensions that have exceeded their quota. The OP is expecting this blacklist to be expunged after the stated period. This does not happen. The blacklist is never cleared down. However it is only in memory, so killing and restarting the browser will clean it, and the extension will function again.

Comment: Update - I recall seeing a Chromium issue that the rate limit was being removed